# Is there any Apple's developer site pages to know what is updated on iOS new release?

Tags: ios

I have a crash by reason of NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription today while debugging on my app. (The my app has been released about 3-years ago) The new description for plist is added on iOS 11. (see [What's difference between NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344159/whats-difference-between-nsphotolibraryaddusagedescription-and-nsphotolibraryus))

My question is;
Like this issue, Is there is any pages in Apples's developer site to know WHAT IS UPDATED. Should we re-scan all pages of the site to find out it? I want to see the listed page. If anyone knows about this, please teach me.

Comment: [Here is the official site](https://developer.apple.com/api-changes/) that lists iOS API changes. However, keep in mind that asking for off-site resources is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is the page I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the major changes which has been integrated in iOS 11 for developers.
Click here :[New changes in iOS 11 for developers](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/whats-new-in-ios-11)

Also i will suggest you to surf more and more and also code more and more to find more details about your questions/queries.